# Spring 3.2 property field populated using @value is found null during method call

Tags: java, spring

I have following classes:

```
    @Component
    public class TestParentClass{

        @Value("${service.timeout}")
        protected String timeout;

        @PostConstruct
        protected void init() {
            //some code
        }
        protected Boolean someMethod(Agr agr0, Agr agr2){
           //some code 
        }
    }

    @Component
    @Primary
    public class TestSubClass extends TestParentClass{

        @PostConstruct
        @Override
        protected void init() {
            System.out.println("Test0:" + timeout);
            super.init();
        }
        @Override
        protected Boolean someMethod(Agr agr0, Agr agr2){
            System.out.println("Test1:" + timeout);
            return super.someMethod(agr0,agr1);
        }
    }
```

Properties file has entry as 
    service.timeout=30 
and is included in import resources in spring configuration.

When I run the application having these classes, during deployment log shows
   Test0:30
but when the someMethod called log shows
   Test1:null

Any help in resolving this issue is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Are both classes within the same package?  Is that package being component scanned?  It may be helpful to post more of your spring configuration.  Also I would be interested in seeing the code for the parent classes constructor.

Comment: Both classes are in different packages but are included in component scan and autowired.

Comment: And the parent classes constructor doesn't call `someMethod` right?

Comment: Yes, you are right - parent class has no constructor which means compiler inserts default one and 'someMethod' is not called in constructor call.

Comment: I'm going to try to build an example off of your sample code, could you provide the config?

Comment: I have spring configuration class with `@ImportResource` including properties file and `@ComponentScan` covering both the packages the classes are in.